# Easy/automated way to reuse or convert Theme defined in XML with Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, xml, android-jetpack-compose, themes

Straightforward question: I'm migrating an app from XML defined UI to Jetpack Compose UI, and can't find any easy way of reusing existing theme with Compositions. The ultimate goal is to define the theme with compose, but it would be nice if I could use our current resources in the interim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Material Theme Adapter](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/designsystems/views-to-compose#material-theme-adapter) to automatically generate a compose theme from XML.